# Multiple where clauses, reading only one

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have to retrieve information with multiple where clauses. I can do this only using nested query. I'm supposed to be able to pull out information of 2 shiftName queries on one command.
Find the first and last name of a staff whose shifts are Classy Evening and Morning Shine.

So far whatever little luck I've found is with this code, but the problem here is it is returning results of 'Morning Shine' but not of 'Classy Evening'.
It's like the nested query is not even being processed. Can someone please help. I'm new to SQL so I apologise if my question is not clear enough.

```
SELECT stfName, stlNname
FROM STAFF, STAFF_SHIFT_CENTER
WHERE STAFF.staffID=STAFF_SHIFT_CENTER.staffID
AND STAFF_SHIFT_CENTER.shiftName='Morning Shine'
AND (SELECT staffID FROM STAFF_SHIFT_CENTER
WHERE shiftName='Classy Evening');
```

Comment: This query makes no sense. We put conditions in a where clause so `STAFF.staffID=STAFF_SHIFT_CENTER.staffID` is a condition, `STAFF_SHIFT_CENTER.shiftName='Morning Shine'` is a condition, BUT `(SELECT staffID FROM STAFF_SHIFT_CENTER
WHERE shiftName='Classy Evening')` is not a condition. That doesn't return `TRUE` or `FALSE`. Instead I think you want a single where clause like `WHERE STAFF.staffID=STAFF_SHIFT_CENTER.staffID
AND STAFF_SHIFT_CENTER.shiftName IN ('Morning Shine', 'Classy Evening');`

Comment: I beg you to start rewriting all your queries using **EXPLICIT JOIN**, they become more readable and you can separate your join from your filters

Comment: Learn to use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 25 years.  Also what is `AND (SELECT staffID FROM STAFF_SHIFT_CENTER
WHERE shiftName='Classy Evening')` supposed to do?

Comment: AND (SELECT staffID FROM STAFF_SHIFT_CENTER WHERE shiftName='Classy Evening')
I've put this thinking that it'll return the staffID which will translate to the stfName and stlNname in the SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

where is a condition.

When you want to do a condition with another query you need to give the column that you want to compare.

You didn't give a column to compare so it ignored your second part of the where condition.

In your case you want the staffID of 'Morning Shine' and 'Classy Evening' will be equal.

so you need to do:

```
SELECT stfName, stlNname
FROM STAFF, STAFF_SHIFT_CENTER
WHERE STAFF.staffID=STAFF_SHIFT_CENTER.staffID
AND STAFF_SHIFT_CENTER.shiftName='Morning Shine'
AND STAFF_SHIFT_CENTER.staffID IN (SELECT staffID FROM STAFF_SHIFT_CENTER
WHERE shiftName='Classy Evening');
```

In addition, I recommend you to use JOIN instead of CARTESIAN to improve your query.

So the query will be:

```
SELECT stfName, stlNname
FROM STAFF s JOIN STAFF_SHIFT_CENTER ssc
     ON s.staffID=ssc.staffID
WHERE ssc.shiftName='Morning Shine'
AND ssc.staffID IN (SELECT staffID FROM STAFF_SHIFT_CENTER
WHERE shiftName='Classy Evening');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation for this.

```
SELECT s.stfName, s.stlNname
FROM STAFF s JOIN
     STAFF_SHIFT_CENTER ssc
     ON s.staffID = ssc.staffID
WHERE ssc.shiftName IN ('Morning Shine', 'Classy Evening')
GROUP BY s.stfName, s.stlNname
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ssc.shfitName) = 2;  -- each group has both shifts
```

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- Qualify all column names, so you know what table they are coming from.